# How to make a laptop touchpad respond better?

Tags: technology, laptop

The touchpad (trackpad) on a laptop is not responding well.

I noticed that the surface of the touchpad is worn in some areas, but not others.

Are there any lifehacks to help the touchpad respond like when it was new?

Comment: The touchpad wears out mostly from the centre. This isn't really a hack, but I think you should consider cleaning your laptop. Carefully open it up, clean it and assemble it back again and it should be good. If not, it might need replacing.
Note that while you are doing that try not to touch the components. Lift the circuit boards from the corners only.

Answer (score 2):

Capacitance changes with humidity.

Trackpads and touch sensitive screens need enough humidity to work optimally. If you moisten your finger very slightly by breathing on it or the track pad itself, does the response improve?

Yes?

Try increasing the humidity of your environment with some plants close by.

Comment: Interesting idea Stan.  Can't hurt to try it!

Comment: I gave it a try, and yes, increasing moisture levels does help.  Thank you!